# Breaking a number into groups of threes in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I am trying to create a function that takes in a number and breaks it up into groups of three : (group-of-three 12345) -> '(12 345)

This is the code I've been working on:

```
(define (group-of-three n)
  (cond ((< n 1000) n))
  (cond ((> n 1000) 
         (cons (group-of-three (quotient n 1000)) (remainder n 1000)))))
```

And when I call (group-of-three 9999) I get '(# . 999)

Any help would be very appreciated, I'm very new to scheme so I'm sure the solution is probably pretty easy and I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- `cond` is being used incorrectly, a single `cond` is required, with two mutually exclusive conditions. Or even simpler, use an `if` expression
- The base case of the recursion is wrong, remember: we're building a list, so the result must end with an empty list
- To output the list in the right order, the input number ought to be processed from right-to-left. This is easier to do if we use a helper procedure with an extra parameter for accumulating the results - incidentally, this will produce a tail-recursive solution. Alternatively, we could use a named `let`

This is what I mean:

```
(define (group-of-three n)
  (helper n '()))

(define (helper n acc)
  (cond ((< n 1000) (cons n acc))
        (else (helper (quotient n 1000)
                      (cons (remainder n 1000) acc)))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(group-of-three 12345)
=> '(12 345)

(group-of-three 12345678)
=> '(12 345 678)
```